# Creating a grouped and stacked chart in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I would like to know if it is possible to create a grouped and stacked chart in Chart js.

I have two sets of data and each set has a positve (income) and negative (tax) component, hence the desire to 'stack' these together.  I am also presenting two cases of data - a base and sensitivity case, hence the desire to 'group' each case next to each other.

If the data is stacked along the x axis the bars overlap, if the data is not stacked then the positive (income) bars are offset from their corresponding negative (tax) bars - this toggle can be seen in the code below under the 'stacked' option.

I would like to stack the income and tax components together, as well as goup the two cases together for each year so the chart can be neatly displayed.  Is this possible?  Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

The code for my chart is as follows:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("MyChart"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023],
      datasets: [{
          label: "Income - Base",
          type: "bar",
    backgroundColor: "#eece01",
    data: [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36],
        }, {
          label: "Income - Sensitivity",
          type: "bar",
    backgroundColor: "#f8981f",
    data: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
        }, {
          label: "Tax - Base",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: "#87d84d",
          data:  [-15, -16, -17, -18, -19, -20, -21],
        }, {
          label: "Tax - Sensitivity",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: "#00b300",
          backgroundColorHover: "#3e95cd",
          data: [-10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15, -16]
        }
      ]
    },
  options: {
   scales: {  
    xAxes: [{
        //stacked: true,
     stacked: false,
     ticks: {
      beginAtZero:true,
      maxRotation: 0,
      minRotation: 0     
     }
    }],     
    yAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
    }]
   },
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="MyChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can stack bar charts by setting the [`stacked`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#stacked-bar-chart) option to true on the x- and y-axis and define `stack` group property of your datasets.

Below is your snippet with the proposed changes:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("MyChart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Income - Base",
      type: "bar",
      stack: "Base",
      backgroundColor: "#eece01",
      data: [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36],
    }, {
      label: "Tax - Base",
      type: "bar",
      stack: "Base",
      backgroundColor: "#87d84d",
      data: [-15, -16, -17, -18, -19, -20, -21],
    }, {
      label: "Income - Sensitivity",
      type: "bar",
      stack: "Sensitivity",
      backgroundColor: "#f8981f",      
      data: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
    }, {
      label: "Tax - Sensitivity",
      type: "bar",
      stack: "Sensitivity",
      backgroundColor: "#00b300",
      backgroundColorHover: "#3e95cd",
      data: [-10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15, -16]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        //stacked: true,
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          maxRotation: 0,
          minRotation: 0
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }]
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="MyChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you Shiffty!  This has perfectly answered my question.  I tried it initially and it didn't quite work until I included the script line you placed in the HTML.  Is this an additional library that Chart.js needs for this kind of chart or just a newer version of the library?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Dusty04 glad to help. As far as I know they've added this feature in Chartjs 2.5, so it's definitely possible you had an older version.

Comment: There is an example from Chart.JS directly available here: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/stacked-group.html